# Copy or Rename file in sub folder under Web App through azure release pipeline after web deploy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps release pipeline, deploying my code using Web Deploy to Azure Web app to different environments (Dev/ SIT/ UAT/ PROD). Now, I need to include a task to copy/ rename one Configuration file (environment specific), which is inside 'Config' folder, to another file inside the same folder. Please note, the config file **is not** under the root folder of the web app.

Is there a way to accomplish this using 'post deployment action' or command line script task? I couldn't understand how can I refer the source folder of the web app for the copy operation. I was referring the following page but couldn't find one that will help me to achieve the task. Any help is appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch

Comment: Having different configuration files per environment is entirely the wrong approach. You have a multitude of better options: 1) Keyvault 2) Azure App Configuration 3) Azure web app settings (which override config file values automatically in most applications) 4) Deployment-time configuration transforms.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for the insights on different options for config files, but I wanted to know in general for any files, not restricted to *.config. 
I will try #4 as this is the most suitable in this existing environment, I was wondering if the transformation will still be possible for *.config files inside a subfolder. Like 'wwwroot/mysubfolder/abcd.config', I will try this out later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Post deploy action script is running on azure (through Kudu API): [Command](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#command)

So, if the file is existing on the azure web app, you could copy it through Post deploy action script, for example, Site.css is in wwwroot\Content folder after deploying, then the script could be like this:

```
Copy Content\site.css Content\site1.css /a
```

Otherwise, you could store the necessary data in App settings or Configurations of Azure Web app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion, so I would need a ps1 script stored inside the drop folder, user Azure App Service deploy task (v4), chose post deployment action, select the earlier mentioned ps1 script file path. Inside the script file I will use the following KUDU REST end point using the site-level web deploy credentials, and pass on the following JSON body {
    "command": 'copy file1.config file2.config',
    "dir": 'site\\wwwroot\\mysubfolder'
}, do you see any issues on the above steps?

Comment: I have tried the steps above, but getting an error, Invoke-RestMethod : "No route registered for '/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/'". I was able to list the content of the wwwroot folder using GET call => Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $apiUrl –Headers $headers –UserAgent $userAgent –Method GET –ContentType "application/json", but the error came when tried to POST the JSON, any idea?

Comment: Finally!! I was able understand the URL you mentioned : https://$WebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command , thanks for the help!!